# nodejs API how to response with image url

Tags: node.js, angular

I have nodejs running as API server, and angular 7 as front-end, 
im front end user will take picture via camera, and send it to nodejs in base64 image type, nodejs will receive it and save it to disk in PNG format, this process is working fine, I am saving the picture in backend server (`var fileName = ${process.env.PERSON_PICTURE_PATH}/${person.id}.png`

which is :

```
PERSON_PICTURE_PATH = "/opt/test/pictures/"
```

I have another page on front end which I can display person data belong to each person, including person.picture, frontend calling this api:

```
/api/person/:id
```

the api will response with json data:

```
{
id: 123
firstname: "john",
lastname: "doe",
picture: "/opt/test/picture/123.png"
}
```

now how I could display the picture in the page: I tried this way but doesn't work:

```
<img src="{{person$?.picture}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append baseURL/Domain as a prefix to data you are getting for the image.

```
<img [src]="domain + person$?.picture">
```

Right now you are getting `src` value as `/opt/test/picture/123.png` but in actual, your image was stored somewhere on a cloud having some domain like `http://yourdomain.org`.
So after concatenating your URL should be like this -

```
http://yourdomain.org/opt/test/picture/123.png
```